# Selected file gets removed when I add another file input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form in which I add new file input fields as the user needs. I'm surrounding the input by a div, as so:

```
<div id="fileinputs">
    <div class="myinput">
        <label for="PropertyPic01">Photos</label>
        <input type="file" name="data[Property][pic01]" id="PropertyPic01">
    </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code does the following:

```
//Add Pic link
$('#addPic').click(function(e)
{
    if(!window.fotoCtr)
    {
        window.fotoCtr = 2;
    } else
    {
        window.fotoCtr++;
    }

    if(window.fotoCtr == 5)
    {
        $('#addPic').html('');
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#fileinputs').html($('div#fileinputs').html() + 
        '<div class="input file">' +
        '<input type="file" name="data[Property][pic0' + window.fotoCtr + ']" id="PropertyPic0' + window.fotoCtr + '">' +
        '</div><br/>'
        );
})
```

The issue I'm having is that adding another file input field as I do above causes the selected files from other inputs to be removed. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: You should use append(), not html()

Comment: Dang you're right. That's kinda stupid. Care to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead of `html()` the `append()` method, this will keep data bound to previous elements as files:

```
$('div#fileinputs').append(
        '<div class="input file">' +
        '<input type="file" name="data[Property][pic0' + window.fotoCtr + ']" id="PropertyPic0' + window.fotoCtr + '">' +
        '</div><br/>');
```